# How to create alert dialog with andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine, alert, android-alertdialog

I am developing game using andengine 
now i need is to create a alert dialog box 
i am using this

```
 case MENU_OPT:
        mEngine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {


             AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);
             alert.setTitle("");
             alert.setMessage("");
             alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                     }
             });

             alert.show();
         }
        });
         break;
```

but getting error 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

what is the problem with code or can i use alertdialog builder with andengine or not.

Comment: I don't think you even need to run that on the UpdateThread.

Comment: Have you already tried Looper.prepare(); before creating/showing the dialog, and Looper.loop(); afterwards?

Comment: Also replace alert.show() with AlertDialog alert =builder.create();
        alert.show();

Comment: Take a look at package `org.andengine.ui.dialog` within AndEngine itself, there is code to use AlertDialog... You will get some ideas from there.

Comment: This code should run on the UI thread rather than the Update thread.

Answer (score 3):

Just make the Object Of Main Activity class and use the Object

```
activity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {


         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);
         alert.setTitle("");
         alert.setMessage("");
         alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                 }
         });

         alert.show();
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`alert.show();` is not the way of showing alert with andengine.

1.You can use `Activity.showDialog()` for alert.

**OR**

2.You can use `AlertDialog.Builder` like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done all the thing right just one change need in your code.

```
 mEngine.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {


         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this);
         alert.setTitle("");
         alert.setMessage("");
         alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                 }
         });

         alert.show();
     }
    });
```

You have to UIThread to display dialog not UpdateThread because both have their independent use.

Comment: the UI Thread is the normal thread, so I see no real need to do this via a Runnable on the UI Thread. Just call the alertDialog code

Comment: No, as per my knowledge we can't directly use alert dialog it needs thread. This answer become useful in scene base structure of game.