# Confirmation Dialog in Android (andengine)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, andengine

I am working on an android app and am trying to figure out how to get a popup confirmation window to display with confirm and cancel buttons when a button is pressed.

Here is the creation of the alert.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    alertBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
    alertBuilder.setMessage("Your Messages");
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Do something with value!

        }
    });

    alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });
```

Here is the call to show.

```
 Sprite p2 = new Sprite(goldMult, 25, 450, WIDTH, HEIGHT,
            resourceManager.spriteRegion, vbom) {

        /**
         * @see org.andengine.entity.shape.Shape#onAreaTouched(org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent, float, float)
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent sceneTouchEvent, final float touchAreaLocalX,
                final float touchAreaLocalY) {

            AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create(); 
            alert.show();
```

I am getting this exception:
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

I saw a post with a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168881/how-to-create-alert-dialog-with-andengine)

However I am confused on how to implement this with my onAreaClicked event.
Thanks for any help in advanced

Comment: I figured out my problem by wrapping the Alert in a new thread within my onAreaTouched method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer by wrapping the Alert in a new thread

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                    alert.setTitle("");
                    alert.setMessage("");
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Buy", new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

andengine uses opengl so you might want to create a handler to execute your dialog on the opengl thread

```
public Handler handler;
```

then

```
handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create(); 
                alert.show();
                break;
}
}};
```

then to use it

```
handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, 0));
```

something along those lines

EDIT: class using handler for looper prepare opengl

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.List;


import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;


import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

import pic.puzzle.framework.Audio;
import pic.puzzle.framework.FileIO;
import pic.puzzle.framework.Game;
import pic.puzzle.framework.Graphics;
import pic.puzzle.framework.Input;
import pic.puzzle.framework.Screen;
import pic.puzzle.picturepuzzle.GameOverScreen;
import pic.puzzle.picturepuzzle.GameOverScreenCustom;
import pic.puzzle.picturepuzzle.PicturePuzzleScreen;
import pic.puzzle.picturepuzzle.PuzzleScreen;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;

import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.Toast;


public abstract class GLGame extends Activity implements Game, Renderer {
    enum GLGameState {
        Initialized,
        Running,
        Paused,
        Finished,
        Idle
    }


    GLSurfaceView glView;    
    GLGraphics glGraphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    GLGameState state = GLGameState.Initialized;
    Object stateChanged = new Object();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    WakeLock wakeLock;
    public static Bitmap lastscreenshot;
    public static boolean screenshot = false,finish = false;
   public static int width, height;
    public static Handler handler; 
    public static boolean share = false;
    String APP_ID = ("567944629883125");
    public Facebook fb;
    public byte[] data;
    public static int custom = 0;
    public Uri uri;
    String here;

    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glView.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        glView.setRenderer(this);
        setContentView(glView);
        fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        glGraphics = new GLGraphics(glView);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, glView, 1, 1);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:


                    if(custom == 0)
                    uri = GameOverScreen.pngUri;
                    else if(custom == 1)
                        uri = GameOverScreenCustom.pngUri;


                    if(custom == 0){
                         here = "Moves: " + GameOverScreen.moves + "   " + "Time: " + GameOverScreen.time;}
                    else if(custom == 1){
                        here = "Moves: " + GameOverScreenCustom.moves + "   " + "Time: " + GameOverScreenCustom.time;}

                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");



                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            here);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                    uri); //Share the image on Facebook
                    PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                                        shareIntent, 0);
                    for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
                        if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {
                            final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                            final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                                        activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                                        activity.name);
                            shareIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                            shareIntent.setComponent(name);
                            startActivity(shareIntent);
                            break;
                                }
                            }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        glView.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {        
        glGraphics.setGL(gl);

        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            if(state == GLGameState.Initialized)
                screen = getStartScreen();
            state = GLGameState.Running;
            screen.resume();
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }        
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) { 
        GLGame.width = width;
        GLGame.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {                
        GLGameState state = null;
        if(finish){
            finish = false;
            finish();
        }
        if(share) { 
            share = false;
           handler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(handler, 0));

        }

        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            state = this.state;
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Running) {
            float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime()-startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            screen.update(deltaTime);
            screen.present(deltaTime);
            if(screenshot){                     
                lastscreenshot = SavePixels(0,0,width,height,gl);
                lastscreenshot = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(lastscreenshot, 320, 480, true);


                screenshot = false;
             }

        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Paused) {
            screen.pause();            
            synchronized(stateChanged) {
                this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
                stateChanged.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        if(state == GLGameState.Finished) {
            screen.pause();
            screen.dispose();
            synchronized(stateChanged) {
                this.state = GLGameState.Idle;
                stateChanged.notifyAll();
            }            
        }

    } 


    @Override 
    public void onPause() {        
        synchronized(stateChanged) {
            if(isFinishing())            
                state = GLGameState.Finished;
            else
                state = GLGameState.Paused;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    stateChanged.wait();
                    break;
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {         
                }
            }
        }
        wakeLock.release();
        glView.onPause();  
        super.onPause();
    } 
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        if(lastscreenshot != null)
        lastscreenshot.recycle();
        if(PicturePuzzleScreen.pic != null)
        PicturePuzzleScreen.pic.recycle();

        if(GameOverScreen.finalbitmap != null)
        GameOverScreen.finalbitmap.recycle();
        if(GameOverScreenCustom.finalbitmap != null)
        GameOverScreenCustom.finalbitmap.recycle();
        System.gc();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public static Bitmap SavePixels(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
    {  
         int b[]=new int[w*(y+h)];
         int bt[]=new int[w*h];
         IntBuffer ib=IntBuffer.wrap(b);
         ib.position(0);
         gl.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y+h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib);

         for(int i=0, k=0; i<h; i++, k++)
         {//remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
          //and so, some correction need.        
              for(int j=0; j<w; j++)
              {
                   int pix=b[i*w+j];
                   int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
                   int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
                   int pix1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
                   bt[(h-k-1)*w+j]=pix1;
              }
         }


         Bitmap sb=Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
         return sb;
    }


    public GLGraphics getGLGraphics() {
        return glGraphics;
    }  

    @Override
    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("We are using OpenGL!");
    }

    @Override
    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    @Override
    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {
        return screen;
    }  
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: I attempted to do this and got the same error. java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: ill post the whole class, i actually called it from onDrawFrame method using a boolean to actually trigger it, thats all i can do for you, sorry, hope you get it